# Creating directory from file timestamp then move file into that directory in bash

Tags: bash

I have a directory with hundreds of files (macos), and I would like have a bash script copy each file to a directory of the creation stamp on the file.  So if temp.mp4 was created on 2019-12-10, the file would be copied to that directory which may or may not exist.

I don't want to write anything to a temp file if I don't have to.  I found that the following code gets just the file and date YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
gls -lt --time-style=+"%Y-%m-%d" | awk '{print $6,$7}'
```

But I'm not sure how to iterate/test (piping it to another awk instance?).  Pseudocode:

```
  if ([ -f $7 ] && if ([ -d $6 ]  #If the file and directory exist
  {
    mv $7 $6  #move the file to the existing directory
  }
  else
  {
    mkdir $6 #create the directory based on date creation attribute of the file
    mv $7 $6 #move the file to the directory
  }
```

I don't need to worry about recursively going through directories.  All the files are in a single directory.

============
Based on some feedback below, I'm expanding my question to clarify what I'm seeing.  Here's the script that I'm using (note the change from hardcoded "*.mp4" to $1):

```
#!/bin/bash

gstat -c '%w %n' $1 | gcut --complement -f 2,3 -d' ' | while read FILE
do
   NAME=${FILE#* }
   DATE=${FILE%% *}
   [ -d ${DATE} ] || mkdir ${DATE}
   mv -i "${NAME}" ${DATE}/
done
```

In my directory there are two files that don't get moved.  Here's what the directory looks like (ls -l):

```
╰─ ls -l
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  9 awagoner  staff  288 Nov  6 21:44 2019-11-03
drwxr-xr-x  4 awagoner  staff  128 Nov  7 11:19 2019-11-06
-rw-r--r--  1 awagoner  staff  138 Mar 19  2019 Pipfile
-rw-r--r--@ 1 awagoner  staff  715 Nov  1 13:53 php_errorlog
```

I'm not sure what to do to move all files to the associated directory.  Is there a certain string which will cover all files (AAA, AAA.AAA, .AAA)?

Comment: You seem to mean last modification time rather then creation time. `for f in *; do d=$(stat -c %y "$f"); d=${d%% *}; mkdir -p "$d"; mv -i "$f" "$d"; done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great tool for accessing file information is *stat*.  So first, ask stat to give creation dates and file names, so we can iterate over each of them:

```
 stat -c '%w %n' *.mp4
```

Pipe that through *cut* which will drop away the extra columns you don’t want (time and timezone):

```
 stat -c '%w %n' *.mp4 | cut --complement -f 2,3 -d' '
```

Now, our output is 1 line per file, with date and filename.  It is possible you have filenames with spaces, so watch out for that when parsing.  This little bit will do the trick cleanly:

```
 NAME=${FILE#* }
 DATE=${FILE%% *}
```

Finally, make sure the directory exists, and move the file to its new home:

```
 [ -d ${DATE} ] || mkdir ${DATE}
 mv "${NAME}" ${DATE}/
```

Put it all together.  This is what you want to run:

```
stat -c '%w %n' *.mp4 | cut --complement -f 2,3 -d' ' | while read FILE
do
   NAME=${FILE#* }
   DATE=${FILE%% *}
   mkdir -p ${DATE}
   mv -i "${NAME}" ${DATE}/
done
```

Updated: use suggestion from jhnc above, adding -i flag on mv

Updated (2): more jhnc feedback (the real brains behind this answer :) )

Comment: That's excellent!  It was the "| while read FILE" part that had me stumped.  I'd looked at stat, but was more familiar with ls.

Comment: What is interesting is this will not work if I use " * " instead of " *.mp4 ".  I have several files with no extension that don't get moved.

Comment: Hmm, that's surprising. Can you provide any details? What is an example of a file name that doesn't move? I take it you don't see any error messages?

Comment: You probably don't want to use `%x`. That gives the last time the file was accessed, not the time it was created (and depends on how the filesystem was mounted).

Comment: You are right. I meant to use %w.  Thanks for catching that!

Comment: I was trying to implement the code in a shell script:
==========
#!/bin/bash

#gstat -c '%x %n' $1 | gcut --complement -f 2,3 -d' ' | while read FILE
gls -lt --time-style=+"%Y-%m-%d" | awk '{print $6,$7}'
do
   NAME=${FILE#* }
   DATE=${FILE%% *}
   [ -d ${DATE} ] || mkdir ${DATE}
   mv -i "${NAME}" ${DATE}/
done

(added the $1).  I have files "Pipfile" and "phperror_log" (no extension) that don't get moved.

Comment: The above is a bit unclear due to the limitations of posting code in a comment.  Maybe you should expand your question instead. I would include there the contents of the script you are trying to run and also the text you type to run the script.  Also, I see that your script still includes the awk and the gls stuff. Can you clarify that as well...